# Maximum RAM supported from unknown chipset for Intel socket BGA1168

Tags: laptop, memory, chipset, intel-core-i3

A client of mine has an Intel laptop with a **socket BGA1168** and unknown chipset. CPU-z and Speccy both were not helpful. The CPU is **Core i3-5020U**. The primary question is **how much RAM does this unknown chipset support?**

The laptop model is an **HP 15-ac142dx** (proper letter casing) and the technical specifications do *not* clarify which chipset is used. Apparently socket BGA1168 supports three chipsets (HM86, HM87 and QM87) though I can't even seem to find information on those chipsets either! This laptop came with a whopping 4GB of RAM and the 8GB stick I installed was recognized by the system however it refused to *use* it (shows up in Speccy though the system still reports 4GB). I tried installing it individually and both slots. Apparently the U denotes "ultra low power" so I'm guessing the RAM might have to have very low voltage rating or I can only add another 4GB DIMM for her? The 4GB stick is apparently rated 1.35v and the 8GB stick 1.5v however again, since I do not know the chipset I can not confirm that either.

> Manufacturer:    HP Model    80C1 (U3E1) Version    96.42 Chipset
>
> Vendor:    Intel Chipset Model    Broadwell-U Chipset Revision    09
>
> Southbridge Vendor:    Intel Southbridge Model    Broadwell-U PCH L-P
>
> Southbridge Revision:    03
>
> ```
> BIOS
>
>     Brand    Insyde
>
>     Version    F.1D
>
>     Date    11/24/2015
> ```

Intel's System Support Utility reports the chipset as "Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework" which is *not* what the chipset is.

---

**Intel U designated CPUs that use DDR3 require a maximum voltage of 1.35 volts and will *not* use 1.5 volts or greater.**

Comment: [Downloads for Intel® Chipset Identification Utility](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/2715/Intel-Chipset-Identification-Utility)?

Comment: @DavidPostill I did and, offhand, I think it said that it only supports 64 Bit operating systems...her copy of Windows 10 *is* 64 bit! I'm open to any other suggestions.

Comment: Try [Download Intel® System Support Utility for Windows\*](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25293/Intel-System-Support-Utility-for-Windows-)

Comment: @DavidPostill Sure, it'll have to wait until the end of the day though I'll give it a go. Thank you for your suggestion. If I figure it out I'll post the answer here, obviously.

Comment: What `BIOS` says? 
have you tried to use `memtest`?
Can you say the model of your 8gb stick?

Comment: What does Device Manager say about the chipset? Are the drivers installed for the chipset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The i3-5020u is 16gb ram max has found here : https://ark.intel.com/products/84699/Intel-Core-i3-5020U-Processor-3M-Cache-2_20-GHz, and the Hp notebook 15-ac142dx (Touch) (ENERGY STAR) specs can be found here : https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c05058845 .

Now are you on windows? If you tried dxdiag to get more info on the system?

Thanks Ryan

Comment: Up-voting for now; it's a client's laptop. Heaven forbid that Intel CPU page would come up in my several searches for the CPU using quote operators! (it didn't) I think I'll send the RAM back in exchange for low voltage RAM. I suspected that an 8GB limit would have been a foolish presumption. I'll mark my calendar and once the RAM comes in and I can confirm it required low voltage / power RAM I'll accept the answer. I just needed an official confirmation of at least either the maximum RAM or the acceptable RAM type(s). Thank you!

Comment: The i3-5020u CPU requires DDR3 with a maximum voltage of 1.35 volts. So while the system *recognized* the 1.5 volt DIMM it refused to use it. I imagine that all **Intel "U" designated CPUs require 1.35 volts for DDR3 at *maximum*** however the CPU page you linked doesn't specify that go figure.